# Can you allow re-ordering, and deleting by swiping, but hide the delete button?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want the user to be able to re-order the table, and to be able to delete rows by swiping, but I don't want to have the delete button always visible.

To enable re-ordering I've obviously included the method to handle the edit, etc:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    deleteItemAtRow(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    moveItemFromIndex(sourceIndexPath.row, toIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

but I also had to insert

```
self.editing = true
```

in viewDidLoad.  However, this makes the little round delete button visible all the time (I only want to use the swipe to delete functionality).  I can get rid of the little round button with

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}
```

but that also stops the user deleting with a swipe.

So my question is, how can I enable re-ordering AND swipe to delete (without having to click Edit, they should always be active), but not have the little round delete button visible all the time?

Comment: Delete by swiping can only be done when the table view is not in editing mode. Please clarify. Do you want to allow deleting only by swiping and only while not in edit mode and do you want to only allow reordering while in edit mode? Recording can only be done in edit mode. Delete by swiping can only be done while not in edit mode.

Comment: I just noticed that what I've done has broken delete by swiping!  I only enabled edit mode to allow re-ordering.  The user should be able to do two things, any time: re-order, and delete (by swiping).

Comment: Does the table HAVE to be in editing mode to allow re-ordering?

Comment: Yes, a table must be in edit mode to allow re-ordering. And delete by swipe can't be done in edit mode - at least not through the standard table view swipe-to-delete feature. Perhaps you can emulate swipe-to-delete while in edit mode by adding your own swipe gesture to each cell.

Comment: I'll just ad an "edit" button I think.  Not ideal, but better than me trying to rewrite basic functionality like this.  I'll raise it as a feature request with Apple - "should be able to swipe-to-delete and re-order without having delete button".  Thanks

Comment: for reordering use this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/reorderabletableview and for swipe to delete you have to implement your own gestures.